# Jquery (read more/read less) did not work after entire data loaded from dataBase

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a "Read more/Read less" function with data loaded from a database.

My jQuery function works very well with data that already exists in my HTML page but does not work with data loaded from the database.

My code:

```
<body>    
    <div class="slider ">

                 <?php 
         //connexion to data base config

                     while ( /* condition */)
                        {
                            //other config      
                     ?>

              <div class="w-slide news-slide">
              <p class="article-text-style"> 
                    <?php         
                       news_affiche_fiche($newsId);
                    ?>

               </p>

               </div>

                    <?php  
                        }    
                    ?>

                <div class="w-slide news-slide">

<!--  JQUERY function work with this parag but not with other loaded from DB  -->

                      <p class="article-text-style">Storea owner Steve Witmere previously arrested for blackmarket bazooka trading. Confesses to involvement in Russian mafia.</p>

                </div>

        </div>

    </body>

        <script >
        $(window).bind("load",function() {
            // Configure/customize these variables.
            var showChar = 100; // How many characters are shown by default
            var ellipsestext = "...";
            var moretext = "Show more >";
            var lesstext = "Show less";


            $('.article-text-style').each(function() {
                var content = $(this).html();

                if(content.length > showChar) {

                    var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                    var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

                    var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

                    $(this).html(html);
                }

            });

            $(".morelink").click(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("less");
                    $(this).html(moretext);
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass("less");
                    $(this).html(lesstext);
                }
                $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
                $(this).prev().toggle();
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

CSS file:

```
.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.morelink {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: What does it do with the data from the database? does it show the entire paragraph or does the link just not work (or both)?

Comment: I load news from my database and put it in my site web. I have table news that contains many data.

Comment: Right, my follow-up question is how does it not work? What is it doing that you don't want it to do?

Comment: The code below don't appear  read more/ read less when the news are loaded from DB. But it work with this: <p class="article-text-style">Storea owner Steve Witmere previously arrested for blackmarket bazooka trading. Confesses to involvement in Russian mafia.</p>. I believe Jquery function should execute after all data loaded

Comment: Fixed up the explanation

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here, post just your rendered HTML. That said, you should be using the event delegation syntax of `.on()`, and not `.bind()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `news_affiche_fiche($newsId);` is not printing additional tags around the content. Given your javascript, if the content is directly in `<p class="article-text-style">` it'll work, but not if it's like:

```
    <p class="article-text-style">
        <p class="another-p">text here</p>
    </p>
```